# Querying large not indexed tables

Tags: database

we are developing a CRUD like web interface for out application. For this, we need to show data from different tables. Some are huge and very "alive", with many rows (millions). Some are small, configuration tables.

Now we want to allow our users filtering, refinement, sorting, pagination etc. on grids we show. As a result of user selection - we are building select queries.

For obvious reasons, filtering on not indexed fields will produce a rather long running query. On the other hand, indexing every column of a table, looks a bit "weird". And we do have tables with more than 50 rows.

We are looking into Apache Lucene, but as far as I understand - it well help us solve text indexing. But what about numbers, dates, ranges? Is there any solutions, discussions available for said issue?

Also, I must point that this issue is UX specific only. For all applications own needs, we do *good*.

Comment: why don't you try some type of data warehousing?

Comment: You can't have the pudding, and eat it too (as *they* say).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in general, you don't want to allow random predicates on non indexed fields, however how much effect this has is very dependent on table size, database engine being used and machine being used to drive the database. Some engines are not too bad with non indexed columns, but in worst case each will degenerate to a sequential scan. Sequential scans aren't always as bad as they sound either.

Some ideas

1. Investigate using a column store database engine, these store data columnwise rather than row wise which can be much faster for random predicates on non indexed columns. Column stores aren't a universal solution though if you often need all fields on a row
2. Index the main columns that will be queried by users and indicate in the UX layer that queries on some columns will be slower. Users will be more accepting, especially if they know in advance that a column query will be slow
3. If possible, just throw memory at it. Engines like oracle or sql/server will be pretty good while most of your database fits in memory. Only problem is that once your database exceeds the memory performance will fall off a cliff (without warning)
4. Consider using vertical partitioning if possible.  This lets you split a row into 2 or more pieces for storage, which can reduce IO for predicates.
5. Sure you know this, but make sure columns used for joins are indexed.